# Jquery NoConflict Problem

Tags: plugins, theme-development, jquery

i'm creating a wordpress theme and i am utilizing some scripts that use jQuery. It was working fine, until i enabled a particular plugin, named 'Paid Downloads'.

This actually made all of jquery dependencies not working anymore. So, i am thinking, that maybe i am doing something wrong. For instance, i am using prettyPhoto and initializing it like :

```
/* Pretty Photo */
    wp_register_style('pretty-photo-css', LIBRARIES_URI . "prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css");
    wp_enqueue_style('pretty-photo-css'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery-pretty-photo', LIBRARIES_URI . "prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js");
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-pretty-photo', array('jquery-my'));
```

jquery.prettyPhoto.js is the actual prettyPhoto file and i have just added these few lines in the end of that file, in order to trigger the prettyPhoto effect :

```
jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

JQuery is enqueued like :

```
    wp_register_script('jquery-my', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-my');
```

As i mentioned, this used to work before enabling the 'Paid Downloads' plugin. I am wondering. Am i doing something wrong ? When the plugin is enabled, i get errors like that in Chrome javascript console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyPhoto'
```

It seems that there is a conflict because the plugin adds jquery for its own purpose ? Any ideas ?

Comment: How do you enqueue jQuery in your theme?

Comment: edited my answer to reply your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and call method `prettyPhoto' when DOM is ready, replace your code:

```
jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

Also 'Paid Downloads' plugins enqueues latest version of jQuery used by WordPress it's **1.6.1**, it would be better if you register same version of jQuery from Google-CDN as WordPress does

Comment: +1 on `$` vs. `noConflict();` (where later is def. missing the trailing `;`), but I wouldn't recommend registering jQuery from Google-CDN. Yes, it saves some server load, but def. increases loading time - Google even got a small delay before serving the reqeusted file(s).

Comment: Thanks, I don't like registering jQuery from Google-CDN either, but when someone does, it's better to register right version. I also like Codex approach to use plugin called **Use Google Libraries**

Comment: This seems to be working thanx :) I have to try it on a combination with the other plugins as well, but the prettyphoto error does not happen now, so i guess it's fine.

Comment: @Mamaduka You can change the Codex everytime. Just add or remove what you think is right. No once cares :) Btw: Hard to register the _right_ version. Afaik you really have to know the exact path of the right version to not run into timeouts and else.

Answer (score 0):

We can use like this way. Its little different. So its working separately.

```
var $jscript = jQuery.noConflict();
$jscript(document).ready(function(){
   $jscript("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```